# Как передать переменную из NodeJS в ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, export

Я совсем новенький в этом вопросе, и прошу рассказать каким образом это делается.
У меня есть стандартное React приложение. Есть файл сервера есть файл react с jsx-разметкой. На сервере я отправляю запросы на внешние сервисы и получаю какие-то json-ы. После получения я хочу перекинуть их с node в React.

***Кусок моего сервера:***

```
var https = require("https");
var username = 'USER';

var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/users/' + username + '/repos',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'user-agent': 'node.js' }
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
        body += chunk.toString('utf8');
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
        console.log("Body: ", body);
export default body;
    });
});

request.end();
```

***Кусок моего react.jsx***

```
import React from 'react';
import Main_projects from './Main_projects.jsx';
import body from '../../serviceWorker.js'

import s from './Main.module.css';


const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div className ={s.main}>
        Main
        {body}
        <Main_projects />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js при чтении заменить php на nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе отличий не много, всё делается также, на примере запроса через [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) получаем данные посредством `GET` запроса, затем выводим то, что нам необходимо (я вывел просто имена репозиториев). Пример кода:

```js
const username = 'Sepezho'; // имя юзера, по коротому получим репозитории в Github

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      body: <p>Loading...</p>
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // выполняем запрос на получение данных
    fetch(`http://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // мапим данные нужным нам способом
      const body = data.map(repo => {
        return <li key={repo.id}>{repo.full_name}</li>;
      });

      // присваиваем новое значение переменной `body`
      this.setState({ body });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>List of repos:</h3>
      <ul>
        {this.state.body}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

В начале инициализируем начальное значение в переменной состояния `body` - напишем там просто `Loading...` в тэге `p`, а в методе [`componentDidMount`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) (вызывается сразу после монтирования компонента в DOM) выполним запрос, присвоим новое значение в переменную `body` - это повлечет за собой ререндеринг, и отобразит нам новое полученное значение.